# What is the story behind the Warp Gates in Cowboy Bebop?

Tags: cowboy-bebop, warp, hyperspace

Was it ever explained who built the various gates in Cowboy Bebop? What companies, what are their construction, how many are there, how far do they reach, and how do they function?

What are the specifics of the gate accident that shattered the moon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think I've ever seen anything on the specifics of the gate accident cause.

The technology was created by the character know as Chessmaster Hex and the company was just called generically the "Gate Corporation"

The first set of experimental gates were between the moon and earth and as you know there was an accident and it blew up part of the moon.

[image: Bebop Moon]

After the accident Earth wasn't very habitable (including rains of rock that killed over 4.5Bn people) so humans moved to colonize rest of the solar system.

I'm not sure of exact gate numbers or gate paths but the series references colonies on Earth, Venus, Mars, Titan (moon of Saturn), Ganymede, Callisto and Io (3 moons of Jupiter), plus a few colonies (only Tijuana is referenced by name) on some large Asteroids between Mars and Jupiter. So you're looking at maybe dozen or so gates.

Comment: looks like a giant creepy Pacman now

Comment: Chessmaster Hex was a prodigious programmer (and chess player) who was instrumental in developing control software (and possibly hardware) for the gates. But there is nothing in the story that would suggest that he actually developed the warp gate technology. There is no mention of him being a physicist in addition to being a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no formal education so please disregard any flaws in my answer

It is my belief that the gate are placed in intervals at a certain distance in a line from one destination to the next,the gates create a tube of sorts in which space is compressed sort of like a man made ocean current but in space ...I know that sounds weird but the gates act as accelerators engineered forces spin around the  gates pushing space inward and in doing so creates compression which leads to expansion that pushed the the ship along .... its easier just to look at the picture I drew and *yes it is crappy its on MS paint* [image]

Comment: This isn't correct at all. In the Bebop verse, hyperspace is compressed space that blinks into existence every 1/48th second. The gates allow access into hyperspace through carefully timed access. No artificial compression.